# Error when installing meteor on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, meteor

I am installing meteor on Ubuntu. Meteor --help already works. Now trying to run `./install.sh` and this gives me message:

```
name@name-laptop:~/meteor$ ./install.sh
```

Can not write to `/usr/local`

I created /usr and /local under it but still same message.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why not use the package from apt-get ?!

Answer (score 1):

Run this command with root privileges:

```
$ sudo ./install.sh
```

or install it in different location that `/usr/local`.

This error occurs because you don't have write persmissions for `/usr/local` directory.